# Logic issue saving to a Tuple

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Person>`, where `Person` object consist of the following elements;

> Id
>
> Name
>
> Age
>
> School

I want to query this List and Save `Id` and `Age` in a `List<int,int>`.

I know that `List<int,int>` can't be done with C#, so I found out that `Tuple<List<int,int>>` can be used instead.

```
List<Person> personList = _db.Persons.OrderBy(x=> x.Id == Id).ToList();
Tuple<List<int,int>> listOfIdandAge = personList.Select(r => r.Id).ToList();
```

The above code doesn't work as I am unable to save `Age` in to the `listOfIdandAge`  List. Can someone help me out sort this?

Comment: your select `r => r.Id` needs to return a tuple.

Comment: why not a `Dictionary<int, int>`?

Comment: shouldn't be be List<Tuple<int,int>>?

Comment: Do you want `Tuple<List<int,int>>` or `List<Tuple<int,int>>`?

Comment: If Id is unique, then @Rahul is correct, what you're looking for is a Dictionary.

Comment: You can also use a List<KeyValuePair<int,List>>, but Dictionary is usually better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<(int, int)> listOfIdAndAge = personList.Select(r => (r.Id, r.Age)).ToList();
```

Or actually, this is C#, so

```
var listOfIdAndAge = personList.Select(r => (r.Id, r.Age)).ToList();
```

For convenient access:

```
var listOfIdAndAge = personList.Select(r => (id: r.Id, age: r.Age)).ToList();

var firstId = listOfIdAndAge.First().id;
var firstAge = listOfIdAndAge.First().age;
```

Comment: This is the first time I am seeing `List<(int, int)> `. Just wondering how to retrieve values from it ?

Comment: `List<(int, int)>`?? there is no such construct present

Comment: @sharonHwk: `(int, int)` is the equivalent of `Tuple<int,int>`. The values are accessed the same way (`Item1`, `Item2`)

Comment: @Rahul: [There is in C#7](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/26/c-7-series-part-1-value-tuples/). Note the "Value Tuples" chapter. This is added in .NET Framework 4.7 (Standard 2.0). Older versions need to include a specific DLL to get the features.

Comment: Item1, Item2... ItemN by default, but I also edited my answer adding labels. ValueTuples are really a gem :)

Comment: So instead of `var listOfIdAndAge ` Can I say `Tuple<List<int,int>> listOfIdandAge ` or `List<Tuple<int,int>>listOfIdAndAge  `. I am confused :-/

Comment: @Rahul [It does, proof here](https://imgur.com/a/Bbg9DqR). Note that I used DateTime as a simple way to get access to two int properties.

Comment: The first two lines will work with `List<Tuple<int, int>>`. The last one, with labels, only works with ValueTuples, so the actual type would be `List<(int id, int age)>`.

Comment: `var` or `List<(int,int)>` or `List<ValueTuple<int,int>>`

Comment: @sharonHwk: You really need to avoid `Tuple<List<A,B>>`. Tuples have multiple fields (which is why they exist), but `Tuple<List<A,B>>` only has **one** field (of type `List<A,B>`). `Tuple<List<A,B>>` does not make any syntactical sense. What you want is a **list of items** (`List<MyItem>`) where every item of the list is a `Tuple<int,int>`. You want a **list of tuples**, not a tuple of a list.

Comment: Please note that there really is no reason to use `Tuple` if you have access to C# 7.0 or above. ValueTuples are great, because of this labeling ability: you can add names and actual meaning to your pairs, trios, whatnot, instead of using obscure `Item1` `Item2` `ItemN` terms.